# Let child element overflow an ancestor div with hidden overflow, while positioned relative to its direct parent

Tags: html, css

My outer div has an overflow setting, inside it is a div with a child that's absolutely positioned relative to it.

I want the child to overflow the outer div, but be absolutely positioned relative to its direct parent. Its parent having `position:relative` forces its overflow to be hidden.

```css
#parent{
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  outline: auto;
  display: flex;
  gap: 3px;
}

.spacer{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:blue;
}

#anchor {
  position: relative;
}

#child{
  width: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div id="anchor">
    <div id="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Green rectangle should overflow</p>
```

Comment: TL;DR I think you cannot do what you want. If the parent has overflow hidden then it will cut the excess content; you cannot override this behavior (as far as I know anyway) from the child, because this is calculated from parent to children. What you could potentially do is to try to divide the blue rectangle into multiple containers, some with overflow hidden for the parts that need not to overflow and some with overflow visible for the cases when you need.

Comment: Thanks @DanielCruz. Yeah it looks like it's not possible. I resorted to removing the `position:relative` from the anchor, and setting the child's position using JS. Sucks but it is what it is.